# Where to modify fancybox pop up element position behaviour?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, position

I'm using fancybox 2.1.4 in a gallery that shows pop up image.
based on the default setting, position of the box contained pop up image in fancybox, will appear fix to the screen windows.
Is it possible to make the pop up image box appear fix to the html page, not the screen?
Where to modify this pop up position behaviour?
is it in jquery.fancybox.js or jquery.fancybox.css?
because i can't seem to find the 'fix' rule that make it default fix to the screen.

Comment: all example in fancybox.net is not fix to the screen; it can be scrolled with the content. what is difference between fix to the screen and fix to the html page?

Comment: yes you're right, all the examples can be scrolled with the content, doesn't it named 'fix' position in css?

what i intend to do in my page is, the pop up image doesnt appear in fix position, but im not sure where to modify it..

from this sites demo http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo
i used the effect from the third image under DIFFERENT EFFECTS part.

i modified the css part in class .fancybox-image, .fancybox-iframe ,,adding 'position:' but still doesnt effect the pop up behaviour :(

could you help me with clue where to modify that pop up behaviour position?

Comment: let me add then: 'i need help to make the pop up element scrolled with the back element'
i mean,, when the pop up element is scrolled, the page part in the back is scrolled too

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the fancybox API options `autoCenter` and `locked` to `false` like :

```
$(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        autoCenter: false,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Where? in your own custom fancybox script; no need to mess with the original files.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WSud4/)**